# Docker container Flask Api not responding to Postman request

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile

I am trying to run a Flask API inside a Docker container. After running the container I get the following on terminal-

```
 * Serving Flask app 'return-nlp' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://172.17.0.2:3000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

On sending a POST request on the given URL, I don't get any response. I have also tried sending the same request to http://127.0.0.1:3000/, my own IP Address but I don't get any response from the container and get the two responses on Postman-

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
```

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

Comment: Have you configured port(s) on the container to route to the host machine?

Comment: Yes, I have written EXPOSE 3000 in the Dockerfile.

Comment: More important is to give the `-p` argument when starting the container. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Comment: Oh, I understand now. It worked. Thank you!

Comment: As Klaus mentioned the port has to be exclusively mentioned whilst running docker container, but i would say try docker-compose way, this was you will save yourself trouble of mentioning ports outside. Also docker-compose would give you the flexibility of running all in a bundle as later on you would need gunicorn, nginx and if you’re going to save your data somewhere a db container. This would package everything for you. Have fun! More on it here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: Noted. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @KalusD. for suggesting using the `-p` option to publish the port on the host machine, this seems to have solved the issue.

we use the `-p` option to bind the port from the process running in the container to the port on the host machine

> --publish , -p        Publish a container's port(s) to the host

Check [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose) for more info from the official docs.